How to update a global variable from within a function
I have an array that is a global var named contacts. I am trying to update its value from within a function called createContact. When I click a button in my app a new empty obj named newContact is added to the contacts array. I am able to log the updated array in a function called getContacts, but once I refresh the page the updated contacts array is gone. How could I permanently change the value of the contacts var?
contacts.js:
let contacts = [{id: 1, first: "joe", last: "smith"}, {id: 2, first: "matt", last: "smith"}]

export async function getContacts() {

console.log(contacts)
return contacts
}

export async function createContact() {
let contactList;

await getContacts().then(data => {
contactList = data
})

let contactListLength = contactList.length

const newContact = {
id: contactListLength + 1,
first: "",
last: ""
}

let newContactList = contacts.push(newContact)

return newContactList
}


Having a global variable doesn't mean it will be saved. If you want to persistently store data, you can save it to localStorage or a database.
